# Can not destroy datatables when need initializing with new data

Tags: jquery

I use DataTables to display data is queried in the database. It displayed successfully in the first time, but in the second time it was not, and that I got an error

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at Fa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:62)
    at $ (jquery.dataTables.min.js:13)
    at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:127)
    at s.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:100)
    at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:127)
    at Function.adjust (jquery.dataTables.min.js:103)
    at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:126)
    at s.visible (jquery.dataTables.min.js:103)
    at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:138)
    at s.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:100)
```

My idea was when I have new data I will destroy the old data table and replace the table with the clone table I cloned that.

```
var $cloneTable = table.clone(true)
```

```
                    if (reFresh) {
                        demo.destroy()
                        table.empty()
                        table.replaceWith($cloneTable.clone(true))
                    }
                    demo = table.DataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        searching: false,
                        data: g_data_table,
                        columns: cols,
                        responsive: true,
                        bPaginate: false,
                        "info": false
                    })
                    reFresh = true;
```

Help me to solve it. Thank

Comment: if the new data is coming from ajax you just can use a Datatable plugin to refresh the data with the new one

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the table to reload

```
        table.ajax.reload();
```